# Creating a new Eclipse project for Phonegap 4.0

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I'm using Eclipse Mars, Android 22 and Phonegap 4.0.  Following the directions here
[Phonegap Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide)

The issue is when I create the project from the platforms/android folder it adds several folders to the workspace.  CordovaLib, debug and MainActivity.  This doesn't seem right.  Are there different methods?  I have an old Phonegap 2.0 project I'd like to update to the latest version.

Comment: it should include two projects, one with your project name and another for the CordovaLib (it's a library project that will create the cordova.jar needed in your project)

Comment: There were 5 or 6 choices for things to import. I'll try again tonight. I never saw a folder with the project name, it just makes it main activity.  Also the example uses the Cordova command, I used phonegap.

Comment: Seems to work when I select only Cordova and MainActivity projects.  Having trouble with the emulator but it launches fine on my phone.  Now to update my plugin :)  Thanks!